# Console mysql xos

Tags: mysql, console

why when I type

```
mysql -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD -h HOSTNAMEORIP DATABASENAME
```

I got

> zsh: command not found: mysql

and If I type

```
mysql
```

it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem with your `$PATH` you environment variables are not set ! :

```
/usr/local//usr/local/mysql/bin/private/var/mysql/private/var/mysql/bin.
```

`$PATH` is where the shell searches for command files. Folders to search in need to be separated with a colon. 
And so you want `/usr/local/mysql/bin/` in your path but instead it searches in `/usr/local//usr/local/mysql/bin/private/var/mysql/private/var/mysql/bin`, which probably doesn't exist.

Instead you want `${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin`. So do :
`export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin`.

If you want this to be run every time you open terminal put it in the file `.bash_profile`, which is run when Terminal opens.

---

Or you don't have your mysql client installed !